# .Net How to stop a disposed modal child form from minimizing parent?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, idisposable

I have created an app in VB.Net. A child form is displayed using the Showdialog() method so that the parent cannot be accessed until the child is closed.

I need the child form to be disposed every time it is closed so that the information it contains is removed: For this I have put, "Me.Dispose()" in the closing event of the child form.

However, often (not always) when the child is closed the parent is minimized, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know of any way to stop that from happening? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do it is to wrap your modal window in a using statement rather than using Me.Dispose in the closing event of the form. For example, in your parent form do this:

```
Using frm As New Form1
    frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, often (not always) when the child is closed the parent is minimized

It is not being minimized, it disappears behind the window of another app.  Most typically Visual Studio when you are debugging.  What goes wrong here is that you destroy the form **too early**, before Winforms had a chance to re-enable your main window.  The Windows window manager is now forced to find another window to give to focus to.  None of the windows in your app qualify since they are still disabled so it picks the window of another app.  If that window is big enough (the "not always" case) then it will overlap yours and make it disappear, making you think it got minimized.

You solve this by doing it the proper way, disposing the dialog *after* ShowDialog returns.  Always use the Using statement to do so.  The boiler-plate code is:

```
Using dlg = New YourDialogFormClass
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok Then
        '' Use the dialog results
        ''...
    End If
End Using    '' <=== It gets disposed here
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very useful description. I have now implemented the Using statement and removed dispose from the closing event.

Comment: How can achieve same thing while using winform.show(), cz I am showing a form and auto-closing that form after 5 seconds, but parent is getting minimized when closed.